# Continually updating value in textbox c#

Tags: c#, textbox, calc

I'm doing some simple calculations within some `textboxes` after a number has been inputted. The code works fine if they are single digit numbers. 
But it fails to run the calculations again if the number is two digits (10 and beyond for example).

I'm not sure if this is because of the TextChanged being used but any help would be great!

My code is:

```
private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (textBox2.Text.Length == 0)
   {

   }
   else if (textBox4.Text.Length == 0)
   {
      percentage = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);
      percentage = double.Parse(textBox2.Text);
      percentage1 = percentage / 100;

      percentagecalc = percentage * total_loss;

      rate = percentagecalc / 0.5;
      rateString = System.Convert.ToString(rate);
      textBox4.Text = rateString;

      volume = rate * 0.5;
      volumeString = System.Convert.ToString(volume);
      textBox5.Text = volumeString;
   }
   if (textBox2.Text.Length == 0)
   {
      textBox4.Text = string.Empty;
      textBox5.Text = string.Empty;
   }                       
}
```

Comment: put a breakpoint and check

Comment: What are text box 2 and 4? And also, why are you checking twice for text box 2 being empty?

Comment: debug, debug, debug

Comment: From your code and question it's a little unclear what is happening. But I try a guess: When you input the first digit, `textBox4.Text` is set by this handler. So when you input the second digit `if (textBox4.Text.Length == 0)` is `false` and therefore the calculation is not run again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check not by `Length`, but by means of `TryParse`:

```
private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  double p;

  if (double.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out p)) {
    // textBox2.Text has been changed and it contains double value - p
    percentage = p;

    percentage1 = percentage / 100;
    percentagecalc = percentage * total_loss;
    rate = percentagecalc / 0.5;

    rateString = System.Convert.ToString(rate);
    textBox4.Text = rateString;

    volume = rate * 0.5;
    volumeString = System.Convert.ToString(volume);
    textBox5.Text = volumeString;
  } 
  else {
    // textBox2.Text has been changed, but it can't be treated as double 
    // (it's empty or has some weird value like "bla-bla-bla")  
    textBox4.Text = string.Empty;
    textBox5.Text = string.Empty;
  }
}
```